# Understanding javascript void

Tags: javascript

I'm using some code to learn javascript OOP and it contains the following snippet that I'm trying to understand:

```
void window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(".item").css("opacity", 1)
}, 400);
```

I've never used the void operator, and from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void), can't understand why it's used in this instance?

Comment: Where did you find that snippet? You're perfectly right, using `void` here is useless.

Comment: It's probably used so as to not return the number that setTimeout returns, instead it's voided, not that it would make in any difference in that example, but stick it in a function and add `return` in front of it, and it might.

Comment: @Bergi at least I'm understanding the docs :)

Comment: @adeneo makes perfect sense now and why you'd use it with a return. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you will have read, the `void` operator evaluates its operand and then results in the value `undefined`. When you call `setTimeout`, it returns a number (the timer handle). So `void setTimeout(...)` results in `undefined` instead of a number.

If the code is really as you've shown it, there's no purpose whatsoever to the `void` operator there, because the return value from `setTimeout` isn't being used for anything.

---

*[I've removed the bit I wrote about CoffeeScript, as I couldn't create an example; the CoffeeScript compiler complained that `void` is a reserved word (which it is, but that's why I was using it). I don't do CoffeeScript, so figured best to just remove that.]*

Comment: I understand. So if it was part of a function that returns a value and you're not after the return value of setTimeout(), then this is a useful tool. Thank you Sir

Comment: @SamHolguin: Yeah, although if the code is really JavaScript, there's no need; just don't put `return` in front of it, and the value isn't used anyway.